# ZPL - how to insert dateTime string in QR code?

Tags: datetime, timestamp, zpl

I have ZPL like this, it prints a QR code

```
^XA

^FO50,100
^BQN,2,5,Q
^FD
Hello world!
Some data
Printed on: dateTimeString
^FS

^XZ
```

What to put in place of dateTimeString so that the following appears when the QR is scanned

```
Hello world!
Some data
Printed on: 29-Apr-2022 15:35:54
```

The printer is Zebra ZD421, if that matters.
Thanks

Comment: Can you not have the program printing the barcode insert the date/time into the data being sent to the printer? Why have the printer use its RTC?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the RTC is correctly set on the printer, have you tried to use the date\time wildcard available in ZPL?
Just tested the following code and it did the job

```
^XA
^FO50,100
^BQN,2,5,Q
^FH\^FC%,{,#
^FDLA,Hello world!\0D\0ASome data %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S^FS
^PQ1,0,1,Y
^XZ
```

check [here](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf#page=1557) for additional info

Comment: At least with labelry, this does not work. The commands are not replaced when building the QR code. If you scan the generated QR code, commands are shown, not the date.

Comment: It doesn't work because those command are used to pull the date and time from the printer real time clock, and labelary doesn't have a proper RTC since it's a great tool, but limited to the label design. I tested this code on a ZD420 and it worked without issues

Comment: I was able to get text block to show the current date, but not in the QR code.

Comment: What did you use to read the qrcode? I've tried with a mobile computer and I could read the date and time correctly

Comment: I have a QR scanner app on my phone from a scanning engine company, it will shows raw QR data.

Answer (score -1):

The code would have to be in the scanning device/program, not on the printing device.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't understand it.
I want to put in the QR code the date & time when it was printed. Scanning the QR code may happen days or weeks later.

Comment: @user3061666 Replace scanning with printing in the answer!